# FullCalendar start view from the current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar, and I set the default view as follows:

```
defaultView: 'timelineYear'
```

The problem is that when I load the page, I start see events from January 1st of the current year:
[image]

In fact I want to start from the current date. For example, if today is August 1st, 2016 the view when I load the page should be like this:

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple enough to solve this problem. I just had to study a little FullCalendar documentation. First, I created a custom view:

```
views: {
    customView: {
        type: 'timelineYear',
        duration: { days: 500 } // Or whatever value you want.
    }
}
```

and then, I set it as my default view:

```
defaultView: 'customView'
```

That's all needed to make the magic happen!

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has an [awesome documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) where you can find exactly what you are looking for [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) and maybe [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/today/). The [MomentJS-Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) might help you too.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineYear',
    defaultDate: moment()
});
```

or

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineYear',
}).fullCalendar('today');
```

(both untested)

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. In `timelineMonth` or `timelineTenDay`, the view starts in current month, but not in current day. In `timelineYear`, it still starts on January 1st.

Comment: I can't really help you there as I do not currently have the environment to test this, some more code from your side might help though...

Comment: Here you can find all what is required to test this : https://github.com/dbeqiraj/test . The file I'm working on is demos/scale.html